# Detect Bluetooth handsfree is connected or not?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-2.2-froyo

I just want to ask that how I will detect the Handsfree is connected with my android device or not. I can get the paired devices but I am not able to get connected devices. I am using Android 2.2.